# HasConversion<string>() stores enum value instead of name

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I recently learned how to convert enums to string at the database level in EF Core (using .NET 7) using the HasConversion method. As an example, I have the following enum and the entity that uses it:

```
public enum EntityTypes
{
    Type1,
    Type2,
}

public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public EntityTypes Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
            .Property(r => r.Type)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .HasConversion<string>();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the entity has an OnModelCreating method used in the DbContext class to configure the entity at the database level as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        Entity.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that if I try adding a new entity in the database, the value stored in the Type column is the string representation of the values of the enum (i.e. '0' or '1'), instead of the names of the enum as I would expect when calling ToString on the value ('Type1' or 'Type2'). Besides using the `.HasConvesion<string>()` method, I also tried using `.HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<ResourceTypes>())` and even calling HasConversion passing in delegates that should explicitly convert the enum `.HasConversion(t => t.ToString(), t => (Types)Enum.Parse(typeof(Types), t))`, all without any success. And the worst part is that when I try to query the database it fails to convert the Type with the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'Entity.Type'. The expected type was 'EntityTypes' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'.
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.
```

Is there something I'm missing in configuration or is there a problem in my understanding of how the conversion should work?

Comment: Did you migrate from an `int` column by allowing the database to convert values to strings? You'll need to update the old data too `update Entity set Type = (case ... [TODO] ... end)`.

Comment: No, it's a new setup so no updates for the data is needed

Comment: I'm guessing that the sql result set returned a string where ef core was expecting an int? The stack trace on those exceptions might point to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations) instead. Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading from or writing to the database. This conversion can be from one value to another of the same type (for example, encrypting strings) or from a value of one type to a value of another type (for example, converting `enum` values to and from `string` values in the database.)

You can implement a custom conversion as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Entity>()
        .Property(r => r.Type)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (EntityTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(EntityTypes), v));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the built-in converter [EnumToStringConverter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.valueconversion.enumtostringconverter-1?view=efcore-8.0)

```
var converter = new EnumToStringConverter<EntityTypes>();

modelBuilder
    .Entity<Entity>()
    .Property(r => r.Type)
    .HasConversion(converter);
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I also tried these, but without success...

Answer (score 0):

Your `HasConversion<string>()` looks fine. Based on the error you are getting and your comment about data being stored as an number, I believe the issue is on how the SQL table is set up for that property.

Assuming this a code-first setup you need to run a migration converting the datatype from int to string.

Assuming this is a database-first setup you need to convert that column yourself.

If it isn't changeable (i.e. you don't have authority to do so on the server), then you can't use the conversion.

Comment: Indeed it's a code-first setup and in the migration for this, the column is configured as ```Type = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(20)", maxLength: 20, nullable: false),```. I assumed that this should be ok...

Comment: I assumed it was just a typo in your conversion to StackOverflow, but the public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) is in the DbContext or on your entity?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect how the configuration for the entity is used in the DbContext